# How to import an sql database to azure for webapp?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure, phpmyadmin

I have created a webapp on the local server that through a form accesses my PHPMyAdmin SQL database and returns results.

I have created my azure website but I need to import my database so it will link with my azure website forms.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, first, you can leverage ClearDB for MySQL in Azure, you can refer to [Create and connect to a MySQL database in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/) for details. Next, you can use MySql Workbench to import your database to Azure. For more details I would recommend you refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/10/16/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-on-azure/.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.